# Export to excel on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, customization, export-to-excel

I want to export to excel, but I want to choose the excel file that has the customized coloring and modification instead of the default excel page. How can I achieve this on asp.net with vb.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show an attempt on what you have done and specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: Choose something on the client or server?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: @Codexer , I am using the following way, 

Dim myHtmlWriter As HtmlTextWriter
myHtmlWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(myStringWriter)

This works and exports on the default excel format, but I need to export on a customized excel sheet that is inside the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look also on [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) library. For exporting to excel, you can start with this code sample:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-to-excel-in-dot-net.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using specific libraries for export to excel in asp.net. For example exist Syncfusion XlsIo, Telerik or spreadsheetgear (This is specializing in excel). In my case I'm using Syncfusion XlsIo and with this customize all the reports in excel, also can use graphics and conditional formats

Comment: I am going to try telerik, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub ExportToExcel (dt As DataTable)
  If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim filename As String = "DownloadMobileNoExcel.xls"
    Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw)
    Dim dgGrid As New DataGrid()
    dgGrid.DataSource = dt
    dgGrid.DataBind()

    'Get the HTML for the control.
    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw)

    'Write the HTML back to the browser.
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", (Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & filename) + "")
    Me.EnableViewState = False
    Response.Write(tw.ToString())
    Response.End()
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your method will export to the default excel sheet, Is there a way to export to the customized excel sheet which resides in a project folder? I appreciate your time.